# What does the last line stand for in this Python function?

Tags: python, function, slice

```
def f(x):
    xs=str(x)
    if len(xs) == 1:
        return int(xs)
    n = int(xs[0]) + int (xs[1])
    if len (xs) == 2:
        return n
    else:
        return n+f(xs[2:])
```

Speciffically, what does `f(xs[2:])` do?

Comment: What are you asking? `xs[2:]` is slice notation as everybody said. If you ask about `return n+f(......)`, it is recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [`slicing notation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1903116) and it is creating a copy of the list excluding the first two items.

Comment: Also note that it is causing recursion.

Comment: @gregb212 Perhaps that was intentional :)

Comment: Yes...it's a quiz and I didn't catch it... thank you!

Comment: @thefourtheye Oh silly me... just assumed you glanced over it. Definitely was not 'in' on that one.